VC_02 Offline voice Recognization Module
i have a VC_02 Offline voice Recognization Module in which i'm connecting it to com's port , the port is discovered but when i'm uploading the firmware in it the RST button is not working so plz tell me the solution for it and there is no physical damage as i can see

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You need to [edit] your post to include a link to the datasheet for the device and, ideally, a schematic. Repair questions or questions about use of devices are off-topic and get closed - so you need to act quickly.

Disabled RST Interrupts are common during a firmware upload to not corrupt the changes between old and new.  It would require a double buffer memory to permit otherwise or a change in F/W.
